# Wifi Raw data transfer

Tags: c++, c, linux, wlanapi

I'am trying to implement a program to be installed in two PCs that allow raw packet data transfer using 802.11.
Well, I want to communicate with external device via Wifi interface. The device has a RS232-wlan module. And to command the device from may PC, I have to send commands and messages according to the device communication protocol.
Any ideas to start ?

Comment: need a little context here.  why not just share with samba?

Comment: Raw data what that means?

Comment: means the data is not cooked...

Comment: Many such programs already exist; why do you need to write a new one?

Comment: WiFi vs. wired makes no difference, they're identical at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

try the lorcon library for raw packets

https://code.google.com/p/lorcon/

Comment: I'm tempted to give +1 for an answer that's just as vague as the question, but I can't in good conscience. Some guidance on how to use TCP/IP sockets would be appropriate, especially if it's more than just a link to the documentation.

Comment: Well I'am not sure about the idea of TCP/Ip sockets in this context since I need to transfert raw paquets so why using 802.11 frame format ? I think it's about using raw sockets but I don't know how to start

Comment: @MarkRansom  I know :)  if he needs a pointer,  that will at least give him something to google for, but since there's so little info in the question, not sure if its even appropriate

Comment: @user1955287  is there a particular reason you want to send raw 802.11 packets?

Comment: Well, I want to communicate with external device via Wifi interface. The device has a RS232-wlan module. And to command the device from may PC, I have to send commands and messages according to the device communication protocol

Comment: @user1955287, you should have put that information into the question in the first place. It's not too late to edit and add it.